# A table using map function

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6, flexbox

I want to make a 2 by 2 table from the two given arrays. The table should look like this:

[image]

I have to use 'map' function from ES6. My code looks below.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

const array1 = ['1','2'];
const array2 = ['X','Y']
class Table extends Component{

render() {
  return (
    <View style={{borderStyle : 'solid',justifyContent : 'center' }}>
   {array1.map((arr1) => (
    <View>
      {array2.map((arr2) => (
      <View>
      <Text>
        {arr2} {arr1}   
       </Text>  
      </View>
    ))}
    </View>
  )) 
}
  </View>
);
 }
}

export default Table;
```

At this moment I am getting a output like - X1 X2 Y1 Y2

I need to use flex. What do I do?

Comment: why flex? take a look at grid layout instead.

Comment: I need to use flex, its for a project

Comment: OP needs to use flex because react-native only supports flex layout

Comment: if the result position is fixed with odd and even, how about generate it on array and sorting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to make sure that the last level of views are flex and have a direction of 'row'.

```
  return (
    <View style={{ borderStyle: 'solid', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      {array1.map((arr1) => (
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}> {/* This is the main line you need to change */}
          {array2.map((arr2) => (
            <View style={{padding: 5, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1}}>
              <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>
                {arr2}{arr1}
              </Text>
            </View>
          ))}
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
```

You can look at a working snack example [here](https://snack.expo.io/@nipuna777/aligned-table).